# PowerShell: the mysterious -RemainingScripts parameter of ForEach-Object

Tags: powershell, powershell-3.0

**Short question**: anyone has detailed information on -RemainingScripts parameter of ForEach-Object?

**Long question:**

I just started learning PowerShell from last week and I'm going through each Cmdlets to learn more details. Based on public documentation, we know ForEach-Object can have Begin-Process-End blocks, like this:

```
Get-ChildItem | foreach -Begin { "block1";
    $fileCount = $directoryCount = 0} -Process { "block2";
    if ($_.PsIsContainer) {$directoryCount++} else {$fileCount++}} -End {
    "block3"; "$directoryCount directories and $fileCount files"}
```

Result is expected: 1 time for "block1" and "block3", "block2" is repeated for each item passed in, and dir count/file count are all correct. So far so good.

Now, what's interesting is, the following command also works and gives exactly the same result:

```
Get-ChildItem | foreach { "block1"
    $fileCount = $directoryCount = 0}{ "block2";
    if ($_.PsIsContainer) {$directoryCount++} else {$fileCount++}}{
    "block3"; "$directoryCount directories and $fileCount files"}
```

Just 3 ScriptBlocks passed to foreach. Based on manual, the first one goes to -Process (Position 1). But how about the remaining 2? According to manual, there's not a parameter with "Position 2". So I turned to Trace-Command, and found that the later 2 script blocks were actually to RemainingScripts as "IList with 2 elements".

```
BIND arg [$fileCount = $directoryCount = 0] to parameter [Process]
BIND arg [System.Management.Automation.ScriptBlock[]] to param [Process] SUCCESSFUL
BIND arg [System.Collections.ArrayList] to parameter [RemainingScripts]
BIND arg [System.Management.Automation.ScriptBlock[]] to param [RemainingScripts] SUCCESSFUL
```

So If I change the command to this:

```
# No difference with/without the comma "," between the last 2 blocks
Get-ChildItem | foreach -Process { "block1"
    $fileCount = $directoryCount = 0} -RemainingScripts { "block2";
    if ($_.PsIsContainer) {$directoryCount++} else {$fileCount++}},{
    "block3"; "$directoryCount directories and $fileCount files"}
```

Still, exactly the same result.

So as you noticed, all 3 commands give the same result. This raises the interesting question: both of the later two commands (implicitly) specified -Process, however **ForEach-Object surprisingly ends up using the argument of -Process as "-Begin"!** (script block is executed once at the beginning).

This experimentation suggests:

1. -RemainingScripts parameter will take all unbound ScriptBlocks
2. When 3 blocks are passed in, although the first one goes to -Process, later it is actually used as "Begin" while the remaining 2 become "Process" and "End"

Still, all above are just my wild guess. I didn't find documentation to support my guess

So, finally we go back to my short question :)
Anyone has detailed information on -RemainingScripts parameter of ForEach-Object?

Thanks.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I did more research and now feel confident to answer the behavior of -RemainingScripts parameter when multiple ScriptBlocks are passed in.

If you run the following commands and inspect the result carefully, you will find the pattern. It's not quite straightforward, but still not hard to figure out.

```
1..5 | foreach { "process block" } { "remain block" }
1..5 | foreach { "remain block" }  -Process { "process block" }
1..5 | foreach { "remain block" } -End { "end block" } -Process { "process block" } -Begin { "begin block" }
1..5 | foreach { "remain block 1" } -End { "end block" } -Process { "process block" } { "remain block 2" }
1..5 | foreach { "remain block 1" } { "remain block 2" } -Process { "process block" } -Begin { "begin block" }
1..5 | foreach { "remain block 1" } { "remain block 2" } -Process { "process block" } { "remain block 3" }
1..5 | foreach { "process block" } { "remain block 1" } { "remain block 2" } -Begin { "begin block" }
1..5 | foreach { "process block" } { "remain block 1" } { "remain block 2" } { "remain block 3" }
```

So what's the pattern here?

- When there's single ScriptBlock passed in: easy, it just goes to -Process (the most common usage)
- When exactly 2 ScriptBlocks are passed in, there are 3 possible combinations

  1. -Process & -Begin -> execute as specified
  2. -Process & -End -> execute as specified
  3. -Process & -RemainingScripts  -> Process becomes Begin, while RemainingScripts becomes Process

If we run these 2 statements:

```
1..5 | foreach { "process block" } { "remain block" }
1..5 | foreach { "remain block" }  -Process { "process block" }

# Both of them will return:
process block
remain block
remain block
remain block
remain block
remain block
```

As you will find out, this is just a special case of the following test case:

- When more than 2 ScriptBlocks are passed in, follow this workflow:

  1. Bind all scriptblocks as specified (Begin,Process,End); remaining ScriptBlocks go to RemainingScripts
  2. Order all scripts as: Begin > Process > Remaining > End
  3. Result of ordering is a collection of ScriptBlocks. Let's call this collection *OrderedScriptBlocks*

     - If Begin/End are not bound, just ignore
  4. (Internally) Re-bind parameters based on *OrderedScriptBlocks*

     - OrderedScriptBlocks[0] becomes Begin
     - OrderedScriptBlocks[1..-2] become Process
     - OrderedScriptBlocks[-1] (the last one) becomes End

Let's take this example

```
1..5 | foreach { "remain block 1" } { "remain block 2" } -Process { "process block" } { "remain block 3" }
```

Order result is:

```
{ "process block" }    # new Begin
{ "remain block 1" }   # new Process
{ "remain block 2" }   # new Process
{ "remain block 3" }   # new End
```

Now the execution result is completely predictable:

```
process block
remain block 1
remain block 2
remain block 1
remain block 2
remain block 1
remain block 2
remain block 1
remain block 2
remain block 1
remain block 2
remain block 3
```

That's the secret behind -RemainingScripts and now we understand more internal behavior of ForEach-Object!

Still I have to admit there's no documentation to support my guess (not my fault!), but these test cases should be enough to explain the behavior I described.

Answer (score 1):

Here are it's details. `ValueFromRemainingArguments` is set to true so your guess is correct.

```
help ForEach-Object

-RemainingScripts <ScriptBlock[]>
    Takes all script blocks that are not taken by the Process parameter.

    This parameter is introduced in Windows PowerShell 3.0.
```

---

```
gcm ForEach-Object | select -exp parametersets 

Parameter Name: RemainingScripts
  ParameterType = System.Management.Automation.ScriptBlock[]
  Position = -2147483648
  IsMandatory = False
  IsDynamic = False
  HelpMessage =
  ValueFromPipeline = False
  ValueFromPipelineByPropertyName = False
  ValueFromRemainingArguments = True
  Aliases = {}
  Attributes =
    System.Management.Automation.ParameterAttribute
    System.Management.Automation.AllowEmptyCollectionAttribute
    System.Management.Automation.AllowNullAttribute
```

Comment: Thanks Andy, you answered point #1: "-RemainingScripts parameter will take all unbound ScriptBlocks", but didn't explain point #2 "When 3 blocks are passed in, although the first one goes to -Process ..." which is actually the main reason this question is asked. I did more research and now I think I can answer #point 2. Still, I appreciate your answer and the technique to inspect parameter. And sorry I don't have permission to vote for your answer even though it's very useful.

Answer (score 1):

Here are some more examples that support @FangZhou's ordering hypothesis.

If you specify the other blocks, it seems to make sense how it works:

```
PS C:\> 1..5 | ForEach-Object -Begin { "Begin: $_" } -End { "End: $_" } -Process { "Process: $_" } -RemainingScripts { "R1: $_" },{ "R2: $_" },{ "R3: $_" }
Begin: 
Process: 1
R1: 1
R2: 1
R3: 1
Process: 2
R1: 2
R2: 2
R3: 2
Process: 3
R1: 3
R2: 3
R3: 3
Process: 4
R1: 4
R2: 4
R3: 4
Process: 5
R1: 5
R2: 5
R3: 5
End:
```

Even if you pass empty blocks:

```
PS C:\> 1..5 | ForEach-Object -Begin {} -End {} -Process { "Process: $_" } -RemainingScripts { "R1: $_" },{ "R2: $_" },{ "R3: $_" }
Process: 1
R1: 1
R2: 1
R3: 1
Process: 2
R1: 2
R2: 2
R3: 2
Process: 3
R1: 3
R2: 3
R3: 3
Process: 4
R1: 4
R2: 4
R3: 4
Process: 5
R1: 5
R2: 5
R3: 5
```

However, if you don't specify `-End`, it does something completely different. The last scriptblock passed to the command is used for `-End`.

```
PS C:\> 1..5 | ForEach-Object -Begin { "Begin: $_" } -Process { "Process: $_" } -RemainingScripts { "R1: $_" },{ "R2: $_" },{ "R3: $_" }
Begin: 
Process: 1
R1: 1
R2: 1
Process: 2
R1: 2
R2: 2
Process: 3
R1: 3
R2: 3
Process: 4
R1: 4
R2: 4
Process: 5
R1: 5
R2: 5
R3:
```

And you can change what happens by changing the order of properties:

```
PS C:\> 1..5 | ForEach-Object  -RemainingScripts { "R1: $_" },{ "R2: $_" },{ "R3: $_" } -Begin { "Begin: $_" } -Process { "Process: $_" }
Begin: 
R1: 1
R2: 1
R3: 1
R1: 2
R2: 2
R3: 2
R1: 3
R2: 3
R3: 3
R1: 4
R2: 4
R3: 4
R1: 5
R2: 5
R3: 5
Process:
```

And if you don't specify `-Begin`, it's different again. Now the first scriptblock passed is used for `-Begin`:

```
PS C:\> 1..5 | ForEach-Object -End { "End: $_" } -Process { "Process: $_" } -RemainingScripts { "R1: $_" },{ "R2: $_" },{ "R3: $_" }
Process: 
R1: 1
R2: 1
R3: 1
R1: 2
R2: 2
R3: 2
R1: 3
R2: 3
R3: 3
R1: 4
R2: 4
R3: 4
R1: 5
R2: 5
R3: 5
End:
```

If you specify neither `-Begin` nor `-End`, it combines the two. Now the first scriptblock replaces `-Begin` and the last scriptblock of replaces `-End`:

```
PS C:\> 1..5 | ForEach-Object -Process { "Process: $_" } -RemainingScripts { "R1: $_" },{ "R2: $_" },{ "R3: $_" }
Process: 
R1: 1
R2: 1
R1: 2
R2: 2
R1: 3
R2: 3
R1: 4
R2: 4
R1: 5
R2: 5
R3:
```

As far as I can tell, it's intended to support positional scriptblocks, where you're going to write:

```
1..5 | ForEach-Object { "Begin: $_" } { "Process1: $_" } { "Process2: $_" } { "Process3: $_" } { "End: $_" }
```

Or like so:

```
1..5 | ForEach-Object { "Begin: $_" },{ "Process1: $_" },{ "Process2: $_" },{ "Process3: $_" },{ "End: $_" }
```

Both of which output:

```
Begin: 
Process1: 1
Process2: 1
Process3: 1
Process1: 2
Process2: 2
Process3: 2
Process1: 3
Process2: 3
Process3: 3
Process1: 4
Process2: 4
Process3: 4
Process1: 5
Process2: 5
Process3: 5
End:
```

Answer (score 1):

I believe -remainingscripts (with attribute 'ValueFromRemainingArguments') is to enable an idiom like this from *Windows Powershell in Action*, an idiom which almost nobody knows (20% of Powershell is only documented in that book):

```
Get-ChildItem | ForEach {$sum=0} {$sum++} {$sum}
```

The blocks end up acting like begin process end.  The parameters being used are actually -process and -remainingscripts.

```
trace-command -name parameterbinding { Get-ChildItem | ForEach-Object {$sum=0} {$sum++} {$sum} } -PSHost
```

That trace-command seems to confirm this.

Here's a simple demo of ValueFromRemainingArguments with scriptblocks.

```
function remaindemo {
  param ($arg1,  [Parameter(ValueFromRemainingArguments)]$remain)
  & $arg1
  foreach ($i in $remain) {
    & $i
  }
}

remaindemo { 'hi' } { 'how are you' } { 'I am fine' }
```

Other commands with ValueFromRemainingArguments parameters:

```
gcm -pv cmd | select -exp parametersets | select -exp parameters |
  where ValueFromRemainingArguments | 
  select @{n='Cmdname';e={$cmd.name}},name

Cmdname        Name
-------        ----
ForEach-Object RemainingScripts
ForEach-Object ArgumentList
Get-Command    ArgumentList
Get-Command    ArgumentList
Join-Path      AdditionalChildPath
New-Module     ArgumentList
New-Module     ArgumentList
Read-Host      Prompt
Trace-Command  ArgumentList
Write-Host     Object
Write-Output   InputObject
```

Answer (score 0):

The source code seems to agree.  From [powershell on github](https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShell/blob/master/src/System.Management.Automation/engine/InternalCommands.cs) I was able to find the following relevant pieces of source for the `ForEach-Object` cmdlet.

The `/* ... */` comments are mine, and I've otherwise somewhat altered the code, so refer the the actual source for proper reference.

The first part is just how the parameters are initially read.  The important thing to note is that all `<ScripBlock>`s are put into the same array, save for `-End`.  The `-End` parameter is handled specially, probably because it's easier to do it the way they did (i.e. it's easy to make sure that something is the first item in the list, just only append to it, but if you do that ensuring something is the last item in the list requires you know you won't append anything else to it).

```
private List<ScriptBlock> _scripts = new List<ScriptBlock>();

public ScriptBlock Begin {
  /* insert -Begin arg to beginning of _scripts */
  set { _scripts.Insert(0, value); }
}

ScriptBlock[] Process {
  /* append -Process args to _scripts */ }
  set {
    if (value == null) { _scripts.Add(null); }
    else { _scripts.AddRange(value); }
  }
}

private ScriptBlock _endScript;
private bool _setEndScript;

ScriptBlock End {
  set {
    _endScript = value;
    _setEndScript = true;
  }
}

public ScriptBlock[] RemainingScripts {
  set {
    if (value == null) { _scripts.Add(null); }
    else { _scripts.AddRange(value); }
  }
}
```

Here are the functions which invoke the `<ScriptBlock>`s in the `_script` data member.  Basically, if there is more than one `<ScripBlock>` in `_scripts`, `_start` gets set to 1.  If there is at least three, and `-End` wasn't explicitly set, `_end` gets set to `_scripts[_scripts.Count - 1]`.  Then `_script[0]` gets invoked, the stream is opened up for `_script[1.._end-1]`, and then `_endScript` is invoked (either `_script[_end]` or `-End`).

```
private int _start, _end;

private void InitScriptBlockParameterSet() {
  // Calculate the start and end indexes for the processRecord script blocks
  _end = _scripts.Count;
  _start = _scripts.Count > 1 ? 1 : 0;

  // and set the end script if it wasnt explicitly set with a named parameter.
  if (!_setEndScript) {
    if (_scripts.Count > 2) {
      _end = _scripts.Count - 1;
      _endScript = _scripts[_end];
    }
  }

  // only process the start script if there is more than one script...
  if (_end < 2) return;

  if (_scripts[0] == null) return;
  /* invoke scripts[0] */
}

private void ProcessScriptBlockParameterSet() {
  /* for (i in _start.._end) invoke _scripts[i] */
}

private void EndBlockParameterSet() {
  /* invoke _endScript */
}
```

It's not entirely satisfactory, as it could be considered an implementation detail if it's not explicitly stated in the documentation, however it gives me enough confidence to assume that this is the intention.  This pattern is also discussed in *Powershell in Action* which seems to have some sort of blessing from the powershell team (Snover at least).

I guess part of them going "open source" and being more "*nix-y" is defining the source code to be part of the documentation :)

Comment: An interesting point is that the scriptblock arguments are processed into the list as they are parsed (except `-End`). Thus, if `-RemainingScripts` is evaluated before `-Process` by naming it (and placing it before `-Process`, if named) then it is placed before the `-Process` scripts in the list. One of the `-RemainingScripts` could even become `-Begin`. (Acknowledgment: this is  a summary of the behaviour described in @Bacon Bits' answer)