# Replicate PowerShell's Write-Host Behavior

Tags: powershell

Something interesting I noticed about PowerShell's `Write-Host` behavior is that it seems to output pretty much anything as long as it's not attached to another one of it's built-in parameters.

For example:

```
PS> Write-Host "hello" "everyone is cool" "awesome sauce" -ForegroundColor Green "what what"
hello everyone is cool awesome sauce what what (pretend this is green)
```

So even though the objects to output are split by `ForegroundColor` it's still outputs "what what".

How? How can I replicate this behavior and make some sort of proxy Cmdlet to allow for this behavior?

I have a requirement to output information to the console if some global condition is true with varying colors. I received this script secondhand and it was covered in

```
  If ($Global:SomeCondition -eq $True) {
       Write-Host "stuff" "more stuff" -ForegroundColor $VaryingColor
   }
```

I'd like to make that a little more succinct so I wrote the following:

```
Function Write-IfSomeCondition {
    Param(
        [Parameter(
            Mandatory = $True,
            ValueFromPipeline = $True)
        ][Object[]]$Object,
        [System.ConsoleColor]$ForegroundColor = (. {If ((Get-Host).UI.RawUI.ForegroundColor -ne -1) {(Get-Host).UI.RawUI.ForegroundColor} Else {[System.ConsoleColor]::White}})
    )

    If ($Condition) {
        $Object | Write-Host -ForegroundColor $ForegroundColor
    }
}
```

But calling it gives an error:

```
PS> Write-IfSomeCondition "hello" "hello" "hello" -ForegroundColor Gray
Write-IfSomeCondition : A positional parameter cannot be found that accepts argument 'hello'.
```

Comment: i think what you want is the opposite of `$PSBoundParamters`. take a look at the `ValueFromRemainingArguments` attribute for parameters.

Comment: @Lee_Dailey years of PowerShell and never knew that existed. Put it an answer and I'll accept that as the solution. Brilliant!

Comment: Yes, for example, foreach-object uses the ValueFromRemainingArguments attribute to process an arbitrary number of scriptblocks.  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16644739/powershell-the-mysterious-remainingscripts-parameter-of-foreach-object/58346208#58346208

Comment: On another note - there is a couple a PSGallery module available that adds more functionality to outputting colours in the console

Comment: @SomeShinyObject - new answer posted as requested. [*grin*]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

what you want is the `ValueFromRemainingArguments` parameter attribute. it stuffs all the non-bound args into the specified parameter. it is more-or-less the opposite of `$PSBoundParameters`. [*grin*]

from the MSDocs site on the subject ...

> Gets and sets a flag that specifies that the remaining command line parameters should be associated with this parameter in the form of an array. When it is not specified, false is assumed.

Comment: Thanks! This was perfect for what I was looking for

Comment: @SomeShinyObject - you are most welcome! glad to have helped a bit ... [*grin*]